# undefined value for array element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of months name and want to append with select element but while passing it with for loop is show undefined value.
code is below

```
var month = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

for(var i = 0 ; i < month.length ;i++ ){
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
   $('#date').append("<option >"+ month[i] +"</option>");
  }
});
```

Comment: What's that? a loop and inside the ready call from jquery? missing closing `}`. missing html markup. overcomplecated building of range arrays? Please take your time and learn the basics or take your time and formulate your question a little bit better. Position of script tag is also important for this kind of question

Comment: I vote this to be closed as a simple typo error, is not even colsing the lop

Comment: Using the array `forEach` method or jQuery's `$.each` method would allow you to reference the index in the callback method without fear that it is adjusted by further iterations.

Comment: You want to go through JQuery beginner's guide first. Having  $(document).ready() inside a loop is a "not read the beginners guide" level of mistake.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because No Effort. Hasn't even read beginners guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question could be simplified,.

So here is a snippet with the irrelevant parts taken out.

A couple of isssue, your for loop was in the wrong place, and you had a missing `}`

```js
var month = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
//append month to the date

$(document).ready(function(){
  var selDate = $("#date");
  for(var i = 0 ; i < month.length ;i++ ){
    selDate.append("<option >"+ month[i] +"</option>");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="date"/>
```

Comment: Although the selector by Id is really fast, it is better to execute the jQuery selector only once before the loop starts.

Comment: @EdgarHernandez  Yes, good point. I was just correcting his code, rather than optimising.  Keeping a reference to a jQuery selector is certainly good advice.

Comment: I like to keep in mind that a lot of the code that we provide in this answers is copied (almost) directly to production code.

Comment: @EdgarHernandez  I've updated to keep a reference.

Answer (score 3):

It's iterating before the DOM is ready. You want your for loop to be *inside* of your `$(document).ready` function call.

```js
var month = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
var monthday = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31];
var years = [ 1970,  1971,  1972,  1973,  1974,  1975,  1976,  1977,  1978,  1979,  1980,  1981,  1982,  1983,  1984,  1985,  1986,  1987,  1988,  1989,  1990,  1991,  1992,  1993,  1994,  1995,  1996,  1997,  1998,  1999,  2000,  2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017 ];

//append month to the date
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  for (var i = 0; i < month.length; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    $('#date').append("<option >"+ month[i] +"</option>");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="date"></select>
```

Comment: _It's iterating before the DOM is ready._ this is not realy a problem. The problem is that the scope is not the same when the ready function is called. If you keep the scope and trait it well there is no problem with that. (ofcourse it's better to use the for loop inside the ready call, but it's also working in the way the questioner did it... if you do it right)

Answer (score 3):

Use let, not var:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    for(let i = 0 ; i < month.length ;i++ ){
        $('#date').append("<option >"+ month[i] +"</option>");
       }
    }
});
```

otherwise, you're printing month[12] the entire time, which is an undefined value, since your array only has 11 indexes.

Comment: The jquery.ready function should not be called inside a loop... or at least I cannot think of a valid scenario in which it would be a good option to do so. It is easy enough to execute the loop inside the ready handler.

Comment: Oh..yeah, ditto what Edgar said. I was too busy looking at the let, didn't even notice. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would map the months to an array of options and then append them all at once.  This results in one update and you don't have to keep track of the index.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var month = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
  
  $('#date').append($.map(month, function(month){
    return '<option>'+ month +'</option>';
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="date"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

make the document ready function to the top and inside the document ready function the for loop

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
for(var i = 0 ; i < month.length ;i++ ){
  console.log(i);
  $('#date').append("<option >"+ month[i] +"</option>");
}
});
```

Comment: this should be a comment. not an answer

Comment: why? I have added the code

Answer (score 0):

```
var month = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
 var monthday = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31];
 var years = [ 1970,  1971,  1972,  1973,  1974,  1975,  1976,  1977,  1978,  1979,  1980,  1981,  1982,  1983,  1984,  1985,  1986,  1987,  1988,  1989,  1990,  1991,  1992,  1993,  1994,  1995,  1996,  1997,  1998,  1999,  2000,  2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017 ];

 //append month to the date
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
   for(var i = 0 ; i < month.length ;i++ ){
     console.log(i);
     $('#date').append("<option >"+ month[i] +"</option>");
  }
 });
```